# How to use helper methods in RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

I have a helper method defined in my RSpec spec which creates an instance of the class `Dog`. But the spec is not able to recognize the method call `dog.good_dog`.

**helpers_demo_spec.rb**

```
class Dog

    attr_reader :good_dog, :has_been_walked 

    def initialize(good_or_not)
        @good_dog = good_or_not 
        @has_been_walked = false 
    end 

    def walk_dog 
        @has_been_walked = true 
    end 

end 


describe Dog do 

    # helper method 
    def create_and_walk_dog(good_or_bad)
        Dog.new(good_or_bad).walk_dog 
    end 

    it 'should be able to create and walk a good dog' do
        dog = create_and_walk_dog(true)
        expect(dog.good_dog).to be true
        expect(dog.has_been_walked).to be true 
    end 

end
```

**Error Log:**

```
C:\nital\my-data\my-sample-apps\Rails-Samples\rspec-samples\lib>rspec spec\helpers_demo_spec.rb
F

Failures:

  1) Dog should be able to create and walk a good dog
     Failure/Error: expect(dog.good_dog).to be true

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `good_dog' for true:TrueClass
     # ./spec/helpers_demo_spec.rb:26:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.001 seconds (files took 0.33463 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/helpers_demo_spec.rb:24 # Dog should be able to create and walk a good dog
```

Comment: Generally speaking you only want to have one expectation per test. Your spec mentions **should be able to create and walk a good dog** , however you could create a bad dog and walk it too (as your walk method is not linked to a dog being good)

Comment: the return statement of your `create_and_walk_dog` is not a `Dog` object, so you can't call methods on this `dog` variable. Either return `dog` in the `create_and_walk_dog` method to be able to chain methods or split your `create_and_walk_dog` method into 2 methods `create_dog` and `walk_dog`

Comment: Also remember to omit **should** in your spec descriptions as you're testing actual functionality and not something that *might* happpen (i.e.: ``it 'creates and walks a good dog' do``).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **RSpec way** of achieving what you want to do is to use blocks such as [subject](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-4/docs/subject/explicit-subject), [let](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-4/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let), [before](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-4/docs/hooks/before-and-after-hooks), [after](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-4/docs/hooks/before-and-after-hooks), etc.

```
describe Dog do     
  context 'good dog' do       
    subject { Dog.new(true) }

    before(:each) do
      subject.walk
    end

    it 'should be a good dog' do
      expect(subject.good_dog).to be true
    end

    it 'should be a walked dog' do
      expect(subject.has_been_walked).to be true 
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Remember to add ``dog.walk_dog`` as the second assertion will fail otherwise.

Comment: This approach is nice because it avoids the helper method altogether. In OP, the test was failing not because the `Dog` class was misbehaving, but because the helper/assertion was malformed. This approach avoids all of that. Don't get me wrong, I use helper methods like a mad man. But, I take this as a good reminder (to me) of how to use the built-in strengths of the tool

Comment: @Mihai-AndreiDinculescu - as a matter of style, do you prefer `.to be true` over `.to be_truthy`? Why or why not? Just curious.

Comment: @jvillian `be true` is different from `be_true`. The later has been deprecated in favor of `be_truthy` and you should avoid using it. Check this out http://www.bengribaudo.com/blog/2014/01/17/2674/rspec-be-true-be_true-are-different

Comment: Yes, as in my comment, I use `be_truthy`, not `be_true`. So, I was wondering if `be true` is superior to `be_truthy` and, if so, under what circumstances. Maybe it's not a good question I'm asking. But, curious.

Comment: `to be true` is an alias for `to eql(true)` and is way more restrictive than `to be_truthy'. It depends what you wanna test really, but I personally try to stay away from 'truthy'. I find truthy to be a very volatile and confusing operation.

Answer (score 3):

Your helper method returns either a `TrueClass` or a `FalseClass` while your spec expects a `Dog` instance. Your helper methods needs to return a `Dog` instance. You should update your code to look like this:

```ruby
def create_and_walk_dog(good_or_bad)
  dog = Dog.new(good_or_bad)
  dog.walk_dog
  dog 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def create_and_walk_dog(good_or_bad)
  Dog.new(good_or_bad).walk_dog 
end
```

You don't want walk_dog to be called here.  It returns true, which gives you your error.

```
def create_and_walk_dog(good_or_bad)
  Dog.new(good_or_bad)
end
```